# Can't install Carp-1.25

Tags: perl, debugging, strawberry-perl, padre, carp

I have installed Strawberry Perl for Windows, "DWIM Perl" from: http://dwimperl.com/.
I would like to use Carp. So I have downloaded Carp-1.25 from CPAN, un-TAR-ed it, and ran nmake.

I get:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

to undefined at F:/Dwimperl/perl/lib/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 1208
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'F:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Note that it's not a Windows nmake problem, I get a similar error when running make in cygwin.

My system: MS Windows 7.

(By the way, I have been running ActiveState Perl fine, and there, PPM downloads and installs Carp with no problem.
The reason I've switched to Strawberry/DWIM Perl, is that I'd like to run a debugger, and Padre's latest version on ActiveState is 0.86, which is buggy. So I've installed DWIM Perl since I'd like to use Padre 0.92).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Carp` is a core module so it be included with your Perl installation. Just try `use Carp` in your code.

Answer (score 3):

> and ran nmake.

why use nmake? DWIMPerl( StrawberryPerl) is not known to come with nmake, generally they come with **dmake**, and AFAIK, their documentation reflects this

Answer (score 2):

1. Carp comes with your Perl distribution, it is a core module. [corelist](http://perlpunks.de/corelist) ([offline version](http://perldoc.perl.org/corelist.html)) shows you the standard modules that come with various Perl versions. You'll see that [Carp](http://perlpunks.de/corelist/version?module=Carp) comes with all Perl versions as far back as 5. There's nothing to download. Just use `Carp`. One of the hard things to understand about Perl for many people is that certain functionality doesn't exist except in modules, but these modules come with Perl anyway. I've seen a lot of people use `system cp` or `system find` because they didn't realize that Perl comes with a module to copy files or to search a file in a directory tree. It's in a module that you have to `use`.
2. Try using the [cpan](http://perldoc.perl.org/cpan.html) command to download your modules. The `cpan` command will search for, download, compile, test, and install any module you need. One of the reasons people use Strawberry Perl over ActivePerl is that, historically, the `cpan` command worked better on *Strawberry Perl* than on *Active Perl*.

Comment: cpan doesn't work well on my system, it complains the system doesn't have an appropriate C compiler.

Comment: @HelenCraigman That's going to be a problem whether or not you use CPAN. When you install Perl modules that include C source code, it must compile the programs. Are you sure you have Strawberry Perl installed? Strawberry Perl includes the development MinGW development environment which includes the correct C compiler, the correct make command, and all required libraries and headers. People like Strawberry Perl for Windows because it has everything required to install almost any Perl module in CPAN.